# Safari 9 change DOM parser?

Tags: safari9

Safari 9 let `form` tag disappeared under dom element.
Safari 8 and Chrome and Firefox is fine.

[image]

- My mac is yosemite 10.10.5.
- Safari is 9.0 (10601.1.56.2)

I searched `safari 9 documentation`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9.html

But I don't find solution.
Someone has any information?

## update 2015-10-05

It was the `template` + `form` problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/svj7j2gs/

```
<form id="first-form">
  first-form
</form>
<template>
  <form id="second-form">
    second-form
  </form>
</template>
<form id="third-form">
  third-form
</form>
```

### chrome result

The `#third-form` form tag existed.

[image]

### safari 9 result

The `#third-form` form tag removed.

[image]

The `template` tag was supported since Safari 7.1 ?
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-template-element

### safari 8 result

[image]

### Multiple post

If it's a bug, it's outside the reach of the stackoverflow.
So I post Apple Support Communities.
[Safari 9 - broken DOM. Is it bug? | Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29045016#29045016)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example? Usually this happens when closing tags (i.e. `</div>`) are missing or duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for the advise! I narrow down the problem

Comment: May'2016 - it is still unsolved

Comment: Still having an issue. Just came across this today.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug.

**Solution 1**: Move the needed `form` above the `template` with the nested `form`

*Example*:

```
<form id="first-form">
    I'm fine here
</form>
<template>
    <form id="second-form">
        second-form
    </form>
</template>
```

**Solution 2**: Add a dummy `form` directly following the template and before the needed `form`. Only the first form following the template will get stripped from the DOM.

*Example*:

```
<template>
    <form id="second-form">
        second-form
    </form>
</template>
<form id="third-form">
    I will get stripped
</form>
<form id="third-form">
    I will be fine here
</form>
```